# Running docker image does not work

Tags: node.js, macos, centos, docker

I'm new to Docker, and I am doing the Node.js tutorial for Docker. I'm stuck at exactly this step: http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/nodejs_web_app/#building-your-image

I have executed this:

```
$ docker build -t user/centos-node-hello .
...
Successfully built c04aea889b03
```

and it built successfully.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
user/centos-node-hello   latest              c04aea889b03        23 minutes ago      667.9 MB
ubuntu                      13.10               9f676bd305a4        9 weeks ago         178 MB
ubuntu                      saucy               9f676bd305a4        9 weeks ago         178 MB
ubuntu                      raring              eb601b8965b8        9 weeks ago         166.5 MB
ubuntu                      13.04               eb601b8965b8        9 weeks ago         166.5 MB
ubuntu                      12.10               5ac751e8d623        9 weeks ago         161 MB
ubuntu                      quantal             5ac751e8d623        9 weeks ago         161 MB
ubuntu                      10.04               9cc9ea5ea540        9 weeks ago         180.8 MB
ubuntu                      lucid               9cc9ea5ea540        9 weeks ago         180.8 MB
ubuntu                      12.04               9cd978db300e        9 weeks ago         204.4 MB
ubuntu                      latest              9cd978db300e        9 weeks ago         204.4 MB
ubuntu                      precise             9cd978db300e        9 weeks ago         204.4 MB
busybox                     latest              769b9341d937        9 weeks ago         2.489 MB
centos                      6.4                 539c0211cd76        12 months ago       300.6 MB
```

Now I try to run the image:

```
$ docker run -p 49160:8080 -d user/centos-node-hello
995bfeef4edd723027480fdb43f097e2ba6a97b8fb1d2e9ec679dc1247f68a84
```

But if I check the processes, the instance is not running.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS             PORTS
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Try using `docker ps -l` to print the last container that ran. You can get the container ID from that output and look at the logs with `docker logs <containerID>` to see what went wrong.

Comment: Check ``docker version`` to see if both your daemon and client are the same version. If not, update and try again. Not all client/daemon pairs give good information (in the pre-Docker-1.0 world, should be more stable after 1.0).

Answer (score 0):

Try: docker run -p 49160:8080 -i -t /centos-node-hello /bin/bash

For more information on the options:  http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your execution environment exactly. I've run the docker-node-hello example successfully using Vagrant.  See steps below.

NOTE: Since the `centos:6.4` image is no longer available at Docker Hub, I've modified the base image to `centos:6.6`.

Step 1: Edit a `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "williamyeh/ubuntu-trusty64-docker"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    git clone https://github.com/enokd/docker-node-hello.git
    cd docker-node-hello
    sed -i -e 's/centos:6.4/centos:6.6/' Dockerfile
    docker build -t centos-node-hello .
    docker run -p 49160:8080 -d centos-node-hello
    docker ps
  SHELL
end
```

Step 2: run `vagrant up`

Step 3: run `vagrant ssh -c "docker ps"` to see if the container is alive.

Step 4: run `vagrant ssh -c "curl localhost:49160"` to see if the `index.js` is running well.